# why doesn't with-open force evaluation

Tags: clojure, io, lazy-evaluation, side-effects

Just wondering why `with-open` doesn't force evaluation of a `LazySeq` and yet `prn` does?

`with-open` is specifically for doing side effects, isn't it a bad idea to be doing something inside with-open that produces something lazy for possible consumption later on?  In what situation would you do this?

Answer (score 4):

The two serve completely different purposes. `prn` is a **function** designed specifically to print things in a way that can be read by the reader. If the thing being printed happens to be a lazy sequence, the only thing to do is force evaluation of the lazy sequence in order to print its contents.

`with-open`, on the other hand, is a general-purpose **macro** designed to execute any arbitrary code in its body in a context where resources are closed on completion of the code. It's essentially syntactic sugar. The macro knows nothing about what the code in its body is doing, or what sort of result it's going to produce.

You are correct that returning lazy sequences from a `with-open` that try to read from an already-closed resource is a common source of bugs in Clojure programs. However, it's not feasible for the `with-open` macro to reliably detect when its body causes a lazy sequence to be produced and automatically force it. You have to be aware of this situation and handle it in your own code when it arises.

Comment: You beat me to a very similar answer. To support what you say, one could take a look at the [source of `with-open`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.7.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3679), where you can see that `with-open` finally wraps the `body` in a `do` block.

Comment: Ok thanks.  It's marking where IO will take place and not placing any restrictions inside that.  It would be nice if there was a construct that ensures strictness inside as well, does anyone know of anything, is it possible?